# AWK Compare Two files

Tags: awk

I learn AWK not long a go and still confused.
I try using AWK to compare two txt files and generate a merged output based on the compare results.

file1.txt

```
budi
andi
```

file2.txt

```
sinta Sep 29 17:12
andi Sep 15 17:12
kuro Sep 9 17:12
budi Sep 2 17:13
```

I try using

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next};$NF in a' cobafull.txt coba.txt > result.txt`
```

Here is the result

```
budi
andi
```

Output I want like this

```
budi Sep 2 17:13
andi Sep 15 17:12
```

Please need your advice. Thank you.

sorry add noted that

```
file1.txt = coba.txt
file2.txt = cobafull.txt
```

Comment: Sounds like you just need to reverse the order of the files in the `awk` argument list.  Also, if you're still learning `awk` it might be best to make the code more clear and explicit so that you can see what's going on rather than using one-liners that have already been through a round of "code golf".

Comment: $NF is the last field, so it is testing for `17:13`, not for `budi`. That would be $1.

Comment: @DopeGhoti usually I find the code from googling thats why in one-liners, Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If file `file1.txt` is accepted as `coba.txt` and `file2.txt` as `cobafull.txt` than:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {A[$1]=$0; next}; {print A[$0]}' coba{full,}.txt
```

output:

```
budi Sep 2 17:13
andi Sep 15 17:12
```

If the order of the output is not important:

```
awk 'A[$1]++' coba{,full}.txt
```

output:

```
andi Sep 15 17:12
budi Sep 2 17:13
```

Answer (score -1):

Presuming that by `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` you meant `coba.txt` and `cobafull.txt` respectively, and that the latter is the "wider" file, then when you do this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next};$NF in a' cobafull.txt coba.txt > result.txt
```

then what is happening is you are reading in first the "full" file.  When it reads in the first line, `awk` sees this record:

```
sinta Sep 29 17:12
```

It then sets `a["sinta"]` equal to `"siinta"`, and stops processing the record.  It then reads in the rest of the file, accordingly.

Then, it starts reading the second file.  It reads the first line, and sees this record:

```
sinta
```

and then checks to see whether the index `"sinta"` exists in the array `a`.  It does, and so it prints the record, which at this points is simply:

```
sinta
```

If you swtich the order of the files in the argument list, it will work as you presumably expect it to.